# Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after installing updates

Tags: boot, 14.04, updates

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 without any problems and then I gave the system update option. After all the packages were downloaded and stuff, I was asked to restart the system, but after that, it is not opening. I get a black screen with call traces after I choose Ubuntu in the grub.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is the error message:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cDGxB72.jpg]

Comment: There may be some issue with the new kernel. In Grub try choosing advanced options and boot the previous kernel.

Comment: Yep! That worked. Got into  ubuntu. So I got it after I ran an update. Does this mean that the updates haven't happened as the kernel has been swicthed to the old one? Should I not update the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a kernel bug to me. Try selecting an older kernel in the GRUB menu. (If the menu doesn't show up automatically, press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while booting.)

If this works, then you've found a kernel bug. You should consider [reporting](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) it. Hopefully it will be fixed in a future update.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just reported it. So I got the bug after I ran system updates. Does this mean that the updates haven't happened as the kernel has been swicthed to the old one? If so, should I refrain from updating the system?

Comment: The updates are in place, you're just using an older version of the kernel. As you've probably seen, you have several versions installed. This doesn't effect other parts of your system, e.g. other applications, etc. You should update your system normally and if you see a kernel update, just try the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is another page on the askubuntu website - after a good bit of information about what to do if installation fails, it then goes on to discuss links and procedures that you can follow for the black, unresponsive screen.

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)